# Tomcat 7 Cluster mode, No faulty members identified

Tags: tomcat

Im an trying to active tomcats SimpleTcpCluster like described here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

I added the follwing line beyond the  tag:

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" defaultMode="true" />
```

But the only thing I get in the logs while starting the tomcat is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.tribes.ChannelException: java.net.BindException: Die angeforderte Adresse kann nicht zugewiesen werden; No faulty members identified.
at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster.startInternal(SimpleTcpCluster.java:660)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 14 more
```

Multicast itself works, firewall is disabled, no second tomcat is running neither on the machine nor in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was an error in the /etc/hosts file